# SonarQube: Create HTML reports without run sonar:sonar command

Tags: java, report, findbugs, sonarqube

In Sonar, we just download the sonar setup and if need, change the db credentials and run the command on maven project `sonar:sonar`, our coding stats and bugs are are analyzed by sonar and make the good html reports. But for this we need to run `sonar:sonar` command. Like findbugs, its possible to integrate with maven and create reports and time of `maven:install` .In this [LINK](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/findbugs-maven-plugin-tutorial/) at 4th step explain. Is also possible with sonar for make the report on `maven:install` command?

Comment: Have you been able to do that? Run sonar during maven:install command? Did it have any side effects? Did you have this side effect by any chance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099614/how-to-make-sonar-module-analyze-the-project-only-once-when-sonar-analysis-is-bo

Answer (score 2):

Like you can see on the [SonarQube documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven), we strongly advise you to first run `mvn clean install` and then `mvn sonar:sonar` separately - otherwise you can have some side effects.

However, if you want to have all this in a single run, this is a Maven-related question. You just have to bind the "sonar" goal to the "install" phase in your POM, with something like:

```
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sonar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

Comment: we need to setup other instructions like mention in this link http://java.dzone.com/tips/configuring-sonar-maven ?

Comment: What is explained in this article is just the configuration of the connection to the SonarQube instance.

Comment: Must be he two commands be separated like that, or will `mvn clean install sonar:sonar` work the same?

Comment: As this is explained in the documentation, it can work but it may have side effects...

Comment: I actually have one of those side effects. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099614/how-to-make-sonar-module-analyze-the-project-only-once-when-sonar-analysis-is-bo Do you have any idea of how this could be solved?